# 2D Enemy Movement Script, not translating from right to left

Tags: c#, transform, unity-game-engine

I am creating a 2D sidescroller, but using 3D assets for this.  The issue I have run into is that my simple enemy movement script is not working properly.  Instead of translating from right to left if my enemy object collides into an object tagged as Block, it instead gets stuck in what looks like a loop, or gets stuck in the Block tagged objects 2D box collider and can not move to the right.  Here is my enemy movement script, any help is highly appreciated.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class Enemy_Movement01 : MonoBehaviour {

public float moveSpeed;}


void Update () {
    transform.Translate (new Vector3 (moveSpeed, 0, 0) *
    Time.deltaTime);}

void OnCollisionEnter2d(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Block") 
{
        moveSpeed *= -1;}
}
}
```

Comment: The first thing I would try is to put your Update logic into a FixedUpdate which is generally preferred for updating physics objects. This is because FixedUpdate is invoked at a set rate / second and Update is not.

Comment: @C.G.  I will try this when I get off work later on tonight and let you know if it fixed the issue,  Thank you for the idea!

Comment: @C.G I updated the void Update to void FixedUpdate, and it is still doing the same thing.  I have also tried changing my collision detection, with no luck.  Do you have any other ideas of what could be causing this?